# Compare the System date and time separately from database date and time to start another activity

Tags: android, mysql, date

It can be the similar question that I have found in StackOverFlow. But I have a little bit different situation then all of them. In my database I have start Date and Start Time. I want the system compare it's date and time separately because starting date and time are in separate columns in database. First the system compares the date and then time. The another activity should open only if the date is same and the time is before 15 minutes the starting time in database.
I have done this so far;

```
private void startTraining() {
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyy");

    String currentDate = formatter.format(calendar1.getTime());
    System.out.println(currentDate);

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    String currentTime = formatter2.format(calendar2.getTime());
    System.out.println(currentTime);

    String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
            .getCurrentTraining().getDate();

    String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
            .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();
    int difference = trainingStartTime.compareTo(currentTime);

    System.out.println(difference);
    //System.out.println(trainingStartTime);


    if (currentDate.toString().equals(trainingStartDate)&& difference < 15) {

        Log.i("Debug", "CHECKPOINT");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TraineeListActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    } else{

    }

}
```

I am not getting the result what I am expecting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your complete code...and also the log cat...it helps in better understanding the error

Comment: You used `String.compareTo()`, which is not correct for this case. The better way is to convert both to `Calendar` and do the manipulation on them.

Comment: I do not have any error here. Here the code is working to compare the date not the time. Another activity is opening on the same date but not on the exact time what I am excepting

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah I got what you are saying but I wish in my database I have the starting date and time in a same column. Does not it make any trouble here. If not how can you do this. Some code hints plzz..

Comment: In what format do you save the date and time inside the database? `MM-dd-yyyy` and `hh:mm` (12-hour mode)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeap that format.. but time is in 24-hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `String.compareTo()` to compare the "time" `String`, which won't work correctly. Try changing the code to this

```
private void startTraining() throws ParseException {
    // current date & time
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    // parse date & time from database
    String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
        .getCurrentTraining().getDate();
    String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
        .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();
    String strDateTime = trainingStartDate + " " + trainingStartTime;

    Calendar training = Calendar.getInstance();
    training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy kk:mm")
        .parse(strDateTime));

    // find difference in milliseconds
    long difference = training.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

    if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { //less than 15 minutes
        Log.i("Debug", "CHECKPOINT");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TraineeListActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you plz explain a bit, how it is comparing the date from my database as it is not working as expected.

Comment: My bad, actually not the date, but the time. Since you only compare the date to today's date, the text only needs to be same, hence using `String.equals()` **might** work, given if the locale used is the same. (`String.equals()` checks the character 1-by-1). However, when you use `String.compareTo()` for time, you will only get `-1, 0, or 1` since that's what string comparison do: -1 if the checked string is located before other string on dictionary index. 0 if the same, and 1 if after.

Comment: Is it possible to compare the date in this equation **difference < 15 * 60 * 1000**

Comment: This answer will combine the date and time, then parse it to become one object called `Calendar` (actually, `Date` is okay too, see the other answer). So, instead of comparing strings 2 times, this will compare calendars 1 time. Then, it will calculate the difference in milliseconds and check the condition.

Comment: Now I get it. You converted year, month, day, hour, minutes and seconds of the current time and starting training time in millisecond. Right??? Smart way to do!!

Comment: In the very end, yeah, by calling `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`. Protip: if possible, it's always better **not** to do manipulation of date & time on string. Also, if this answer helps you, you could accept it as the correct answer.